# JSON POST using PHP

Tags: php, json, web-services

I have created that needs to take post values and return a *JSON* encoded array.

That all worked fine until I was told I would need to post the form data with a `content-type` of `application/json`.

Since then I cannot return any values from the web service and it is definitely something to do with how I am filtering their post values
Basically I know that it is due to the $_POST values not being set but I can't find what I need to put instead of the $_POST. I tried json_decode($_POST), file_get_contents("php://input") and a number of other ways but I was shooting in the dark a bit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sharing some code would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have empty $_POST. If your web-server wants see data in json-format you need to read the raw input and then parse it with JSON decode You need something like that

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$result = json_decode($input);
```